# Using an External CA for SSL Certificate for interlal IIS website

Tags: ssl, iis, self-signed, ca

I have a website built and running on IIS / Win 2012R2, its only accessible within my local network and will never reach the outside world.

Currently, I'm using a self-signed SSL certificate that I have installed on all my windows machines, no problem!

I now need to get the website to work on Android 7.7 tablets, without the chrome browser complaining about the use of a self-signed certificate. I'm not able to install my Self-Signed certificate on these devices so I need to use an online CA.

The question is, how can I link an online CA to our internal website? The key issue being I don't have a domain, the path to access the website is https://servername/website

Is this even possible at all?

Comment: Dig more about those Android devices. If they are only on your local network, I see no reason why you cannot install your self-signed certificate on them. Usually CAs don't issue certificates for your internal network usage, and you should build your own internal CA (like Active Directory Certificate Services) instead.

Comment: @LexLi thanks for your reply. I agree with you in that it doesn't feel like the right way to approach it but I'm having such problems getting Android 7.7.7 to accept my certificates, they work fine on windows... When I go to install on Android it does not show the CA on import and I don't know how to export the certificate with that bit in it.